# Django Filter all objects that contain latest date

Tags: django

I'm performing two queries to obtain all of the latest matches as shown below. Is there a more efficient way to retrieve all match objects that have the same latest date?

```
class Match(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField()
    round_date = models.DateField()

date = Match.objects.latest('round_date').round_date
Match.objects.filter(round_date=date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**`Subquery`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) here:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

maximal = Match.objects.order_by('-round_date').values('round_date')[:1]
Match.objects.filter(round_date=Subquery(maximal))
```

which will perform a single query:

```
SELECT match.id, match.round_date
FROM match
WHERE match.round_date = (
    SELECT U0.round_date
    FROM match U0
    ORDER BY U0.round_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

The `maximal` query is thus - unless you would of course "consume" it - not evaluated, but is used to construct a subquery.

In case the field on which you order can be `NULL`able, this is not the case here, I advise to use an `.order_by(F('round_date').desc(nulls_last=True))`.